# Invoking a PL/SQL function with to_char from SQL statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have built this function to print a list of all projects along with the total amount of pledges for each one of them. I need to format the output to show the `$` sign, comma, and two decimal places for the value.

So far I can get the result but without the formatting. I included `to_char` in the function.

When I invoke it I receive this error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.DD_PROJECT_SF", line 19
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:
```

*Action:

Here is my function:

```
create or replace function DD_PROJECT_SF (

project_id dd_project.idproj%type)

return number is 

pledge_amount dd_pledge.pledgeamt%type;
project_name  dd_project.projname%type;
projid     dd_pledge.idproj%type;

begin 

select idproj, projname into   projid, project_name from  dd_project

where idproj = project_id;

select to_char(sum(pledgeamt), '$9,990.99')  into pledge_amount from dd_pledge 
where idproj = project_id;

if (pledge_amount = 0) then
return 0;
else
return pledge_amount;
end if;

return pledge_amount;

end  DD_PROJECT_SF;
```

And this is the invoking SQL statement:

```
select idproj, projname, DD_PROJECT_SF(idproj) from dd_project;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the type of `dd_pledge.pledgeamt`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson it's number (8,2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you're returning a number and selecting a varchar into a number variable. You need all your data types to be the same. As you want to return a character it might be easier to select a number into a number and then transform the variable to a character as you return it.

Secondly, you have a lot of unnecessary code in here. It could be simplified to:

```
create or replace function DD_PROJECT_SF (
    Pproject_id dd_project.idproj%type 
    ) return varchar2 is 

   -- As you're summing you don-t know
   -- whether the sum will fit in the same
   -- data type so extend to the maximum
   pledge_amount number;

begin 

   -- select a number
   select sum(pledgeamt) into pledge_amount 
     from dd_pledge 
    where idproj = Pproject_id;

   -- return a character
   return to_char(pledge_amount, '$9,990.99');

end  DD_PROJECT_SF;
```

As a side note, as you're summing how do you know that the maximum amount will be less than $10,000? You might want to extend this to take into account a much larger number.

Lastly, this is the sort of thing that can easily be done in a SQL statement rather than PL/SQL. Consider using one if possible.

---

You've commented:

> ... I used the if statement here as I want the function to show me
>   zero instead of null where the total is 0. so how may I include it in
>   your code.I tried to but not succeeded

This function will always return 0 if the SUM of the pledges is 0. It will *only* return NULL if there's no data relating to this `IDPROJ` in the table.

Personally, I would not disguise the fact that you have no data by returning a 0 if this is the case. A NULL and a 0 are logically distinct; you lose this distinction if you do this.

Having said that, if you always want to return a 0 if you have no data then you can use [`NVL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions119.htm#SQLRF00684) to do so. Change your return statement to the following:

```
return to_char(nvl(pledge_amount, 0), '$9,990.99');
```

Comment: well for instance I used the if statement here as I want the function to show me zero instead of null where the total is 0. so how may I include it in your code.I tried to but not succeeded

Comment: I've updated my answer @user2396035 as it wouldn't fit in a comment.